# jQuery highlight table row, keep after refresh

Tags: jquery, html-table, onclick, refresh, highlight

I have a jQuery function:

```
function highlightrow(obj) {
    if ($(obj).attr("style")=='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 102);' || $(obj).attr("style")=='background-color: #ffff66;') {
        $(obj).removeAttr("style");
    } else {
        $(obj).attr("style","background-color: #ffff66;");
    }
}
```

it highlights and removes highlight with on click event

```
<tr onclick="highlightrow(this);" >
```

how to make that the highlighted row keep after page refresh?

Comment: By storing the info which row is to highlight somewhere …?

Answer (score 1):

As cbroe suggested in his comment, you would need to save the clicked status of those rows somewhere, was it local storage or cookie.
In addition, I would also use classes instead of the style attribute so that if you need to change your colors, you don't have to change your JS.